# Manipulate array response in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, javascript-objects

I have this array of objects response from the back end, I would like to manipulate it in the front end.

Current response:

```
const availableModules = [
  {
    key: "tshirt",
    color: "#305b2d",
    status: "active",
  },
  {
    key: "tshirt",
    color: "#066da0",
    status: "active step 2",
  },
  {
    key: "tshirt",
    color: "#772016",
    status: "active step 3",
  },
  {
    key: "tshirt",
    color: "#742016",
    status: "canceled",
  },
  {
    key: "short",
    color: "#702010",
    status: "refunded",
  },
];
```

How can I manipulate it to have all the active status("active, active step 2 & active step 3") inside an array of objects like the following?

Any suggestion??

```
const availableModules = [
  {
    key: "tshirt",
    color: "#305b2d",
    status: "active",
    modules: 
    [
    { key: "tshirt",
    color: "#066da0",
    status: "active step 2"}, 
    {  key: "tshirt",
    color: "#772016",
    status: "active step 3"}
    ],
  },
  {
    key: "tshirt",
    color: "#742016",
    status: "canceled",
  },
  {
    key: "short",
    color: "#702010",
    status: "refunded",
  },
];
```

This is my progress so far...

```
const arr = availableModules.map((group) => {
for (const groupItem in group) {
  console.log(`${groupItem}: ${group[groupItem]}`);
 }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const availableModules = [
  {
    key: "tshirt",
    color: "#305b2d",
    status: "active",
  },
  {
    key: "tshirt",
    color: "#066da0",
    status: "active step 2",
  },
  {
    key: "tshirt",
    color: "#772016",
    status: "active step 3",
  },
  {
    key: "tshirt",
    color: "#742016",
    status: "canceled",
  },
  {
    key: "short",
    color: "#702010",
    status: "refunded",
  },
];

const activeModules = availableModules.filter((m) =>
  m.status.includes("active")
);

const otherStatusModules = availableModules.filter(
  (m) => !m.status.includes("active")
);

const newModules = [
  {
    ...activeModules[0],
    modules: activeModules.filter((_, idx) => idx > 0),
  },
  ...otherStatusModules,
];

console.log(newModules);
```